# Rails as API - Delete current user using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a small problem, I am using Rails 5.0.1 as API only and Devise to manage users. But I can not find a way to allow the user to be able of deleting himself, this is my controller method:

```
def delete_user
    begin
      User.find(current_user.id).destroy
      render(nothing: true, status: :ok)
    rescue => e
      render(json: {errors: e.message}, status: :unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
```

My rspec gives the following message:

> RuntimeError: Can't modify frozen hash

So I changed the method to find the user with the current_user by id like this:

```
def delete_user
 begin
   User.find(current_user.id).destroy
   render(nothing: true, status: :ok)
 rescue => e
   render(json: {errors: e.message}, status: :unprocessable_entity)
 end
end
```

The rspec message is:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=1614

This is the Rspec code:

```
describe 'DELETE #delete_user' do
    login_user

    it 'expect to render 200 if delete' do
      delete :delete_user
      expect(response.body).to be_empty
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
```

But the user does exist, I also tried sign out the user before deleting but also did not work. So does anyone knows how can I allow the user to delete himself?

I have seen some solutions, but used views and using a Link_to, but I do not use views because is a API.

Comment: Unless you show the rspec code how are we supposed to know what's causing the error ;)

Comment: I see that the two `delete_user` methods are identical. Can you please correct this?

As an aside, assuming that `delete_user` is in `UsersController`, and that there is not other method called `delete`, you should consider renaming `delete_user` to `delete`.